# Domain Driven Design Identities and Value Objects

Tags: domain-driven-design

In Vaughn Vernon Implementing Domain-driven Design book and [code](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples_NET), he uses a mix of `Identity` and `ValueObject` for identifiers.

```
public interface IIdentity
{
    string Id { get; }
}

public abstract class Identity : IEquatable<Identity>, IIdentity
{
    protected Identity() => this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    protected Identity(string id) => this.Id = id;
    // Currently for Entity Framework, set must be protected, not private. will be fixed in EF 6.
    public string Id { get; protected set; }

    public bool Equals(Identity id)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, id)) return true;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, id)) return false;
        return this.Id.Equals(id.Id);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object anotherObject) => Equals(anotherObject as Identity);
    public override int GetHashCode() => (this.GetType().GetHashCode() * 907) + this.Id.GetHashCode();
    public override string ToString() => this.GetType().Name + " [Id=" + Id + "]";
}
```

And value objects:

```
public abstract class ValueObject
{
    // Returns all components of a value objects which constitute its identity.
    protected abstract IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;
        var vo = obj as ValueObject;
        return GetEqualityComponents().SequenceEqual(vo.GetEqualityComponents());
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => HashCodeHelper.CombineHashCodes(GetEqualityComponents());
}
```

I see in some cases a `ValueObject` is used as an identity:

```
public class TaskId : ValueObject
{
    public TaskId()
        : this(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper().Substring(0, 8))
    {
    }

    public TaskId(string id)
    {
        AssertionConcern.AssertArgumentNotEmpty(id, "The id must be provided.");
        AssertionConcern.AssertArgumentLength(id, 8, "The id must be 8 characters or less.");
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return this.Id;
    }
}
```

And other cases they are a pure `Identity`:

```
public class ForumId : SaaSOvation.Common.Domain.Model.Identity
{
    public ForumId(string id) : base(id) { }
}
```

To me, all values should be a [value object](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/SeedWork/ValueObject.cs), including *identities*, so I don't understand the differentiation here in having an explicit `Identity` type.

With his demo code, how/why is he choosing the above approaches to modeling identity and is there any advantage/disadvantage over the other?

Comment: Value Objects often don't include domain invariants and business knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both implementations are comparing properties for equality, so both follow the  *concept of a value object*. The ***Identity*** class is dedicated to be a reusable value object for custom identity types which still share the same requirements (using an arbitrary string, usually created from a GUID/UUID). Still a value object,but if no other properties than a string id are needed this one can be used in such cases while still strongly typing different types of identities with separate derived classes (like ForumId).

The ***ValueObject*** class on the other hand is dealing with arbitrary properties that need to be compared in the respective derived classes.

I think the intention to derive ***TaskId*** from *ValueObject* rather than from *Identity* becomes clearer if you look at the constructor. In this case a **specific business rule** - *the id must be eight characters or less* - needs to be fulfilled upon construction which would not make sense for the definition of the general identity implementation.